# Write file in ruby with russian and polish symbols

Tags: ruby, encoding, streamwriter

I need to write to html file some data, which could be non-english, now my code:

```
File.open('text2.html', 'wb') do |fo|
  fo.write body_text3
end
```

also i try

```
File.open('text2.html', 'wb') do |fo|
  fo.write body_text3.encode('UTF-8')
end
```

but i get error: :

> in `encode': "\xD0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
>   (Encoding::UndefinedCon...

**how could i save webpage with russian symbols?**

also what i need to write, so that i could operate with nokogiri with my russian page? need i to do some conversations, or just # coding: utf-8  on top of code is enough?

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score 4):

can you try below ?

```
File.open('text2.html', 'wb') do |fo|
  fo.write body_text3.force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT').encode('UTF-8')
end
```

***Here is the explanation:***

> Here, we start with ***UTF-8***, then we let Ruby know that it’s actually ***ASCII-8BIT***. It isn’t, so that just results in garbage. We then ask Ruby to give us that encoded back in to ***UTF-8***.

Good blog by Yehuda Katz: [**Ruby 1.9 Encodings: A Primer and the Solution for Rails**](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/).

Comment: btw, for example my string is: РЇР·С‹РєРѕРІР°СЏ РІРµСЂСЃРёС  but as result i must see Языковая версия, this http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/  decoder say CP1251 → UTF-8, i try this, but i see non-normal symbols too

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Can you check `Encoding.defualt_encoding` and `your_string.encoding`? and let me know.

Comment: undefined method `defualt_encoding' for Encoding:Class   for Encoding.defualt_encoding and ASCII-8BIT for string.encoding

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I had typo.. :) do now `Encoding.default_encoding`

Comment: still 123.rb:151:in `<main>': undefined method `default_encoding' for Encoding:Class (no method error) also http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Encoding.html i didn't see such method, also .default_external gives IBM866

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38656/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-brabertaser1992)